# Using a n-1 calculation, within a loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to use n-1 to draw a items within a loop. Obviously the first observation, n-1 wont have an item, so I assume that is the reason my script isn't working. Here is some example data.

```
df = data.frame(Week=seq(1,10,by=1),  X1 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
container <- data.frame(numeric(nrow(df)))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { container[i,] <- df$X1[i] + 0.5*container[ i-1,] }
```

I get this error message

```
Error in 1:nrow(df) : argument of length 0
```

Is there a way to adjust the script to get this result?

```
> container
   numeric.nrow.df..
1          0.0000000
2          0.0000000
3          1.0000000
4          0.5000000
5          0.2500000
6          0.1250000
7          0.0625000
8          0.0312500
9          0.0156250
10         0.0078125
```

I have used a workaround by adding a row of zeros, starting the loop from row 2, then removing the first row. This is quite unwieldy. If it's possible to modify in script it would be much simpler.
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't get it, if you start the loop from the second row you get exactly your desired output, where is the issue?

Comment: if the X1 value 1 is in row 1, then starting a loop from row 2 excludes it. It wont work with this, df = data.frame(Week=seq(1,10,by=1),  X1 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

Comment: Can you paste this in your question with the desired output for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to achieve this, using the df in your question

```
> df = data.frame(Week=seq(1,10,by=1),  X1 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
> df$X1+0.5*rbind(0,head(container,-1))

   numeric.nrow.df..
1          0.0000000
2          0.0000000
3          1.0000000
4          0.5000000
5          0.2500000
6          0.1250000
7          0.0625000
8          0.0312500
9          0.0156250
10         0.0078125
```

For your second dataframe

```
> df = data.frame(Week=seq(1,10,by=1), X1 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
> df$X1+0.5*rbind(0,head(container,-1))

   numeric.nrow.df..
1          1.0000000
2          0.0000000
3          0.0000000
4          0.5000000
5          0.2500000
6          0.1250000
7          0.0625000
8          0.0312500
9          0.0156250
10         0.0078125
```

Comment: do I need to change the container at default?